# How to emulate the Logitech G-Shift key in Logitech G-Hub LUA script or AutoHotKey?

Tags: lua, autohotkey, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I need to emulate the G-Shift key on my keyboard as I only have a compatible mouse and no compatible keyboard for doing so, and so I am not able to bind any keyboard key to be G-Shift.

Is there a way to use LUA into my G-Hub software to do so?
Or maybe use some extra apps like AutoHotKey??

Thank you very much.

Comment: AutoHotKey is unable to change internal variable of Logitech mouse driver.  The only way to use G-Shift on your mouse is to bind G-Shift to a mouse button.  Or you can implement similar logic in a Lua script (mouse button action would depend on `Shift`, `Alt`, `Ctrl` keyboard keys or `ScrollLock`, `NumLock`, `CapsLock` keyboard LEDs).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was trying to avoid binding it to one of the mouse buttons as I would inevitably lost that mouse button for other use. I would like to bind it on `Shift`, `Alt`, `Ctrl` keyboard keys or `ScrollLock`, `NumLock`, `CapsLock` using LUA but I am unable to find anything in the Logitech's LUA scripting guide.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to implement two different actions on mouse#6 press depending on ScrollLock LED.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event=="MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg==6 then
        if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
            -- Do something when ScrollLock LED is on
        else
            -- Do something when ScrollLock LED is off
        end
    end
end
```

To depend on `Shift` use `IsModifierPressed("shift")` instead of `IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")`

In the `Do something` section of the code:
For example, you can create a macro in LGS/GHUB and invoke `PlayMacro("YOUR_MACRO_NAME")` in the Lua code.